# How to define defaultProps using arrow function component (rafce)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-props, arrow-functions

So I'm curious if there is an option to declare **defaultProps with react arrow function component**?

I've only found solutions for class based components and functional components, declared by word function at official react documentation.

**class based:**

```
class Greeting extends React.Component {
static defaultProps = {
    name: 'Meggie'
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>Hello, {this.props.name}</div>
    )
  }
}
```

**function based:**

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
function HelloWorldComponent({ name }) {
  return (
    <div>Hello, {name}</div>
  )
}

HelloWorldComponent.defaultProps = {
  name: "Meggie"
}

export default HelloWorldComponent
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good approach is to define the default props in the function arguments like:

```
function HelloWorldComponent({ name = 'Meggie' }) { ... }
```

Or with **arrow functions**:

```
const HelloWorldComponent = ({ name = 'Meggie' }) => { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using Typescript, here is the code with interface:

```js
interface IProps {
    name?: string;
}

const Test = ({name = 'Meggie'}: Iprops) => {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Add question mark works for me.